# SignalR mysql connection string .NET Core

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR with MySQL in .NET Core. I need to pass a dynamic connection string for SignalR.

I see `services.AddSignalR().AddSqlServer()` for SQL Server but I'm not able to see a similar one for MySql.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think signalr supports mysql out of box. Not suprising considering mysql does not have notification services.

Comment: Would you kindly share your your details implementation or hows your hub designed?

Answer (score 0):

> I see services.AddSignalR().AddSqlServer() for SQL Server but I'm not
> able to see a similar one for MySql.

I am not sure in which way you are try to pass the dynamic connection string. While I was investigating your issue, I found that there's no overloading for `AddSignalR()` in order to pass the Database instance or connection string, at least the way, you are trying which is `services.AddSignalR().AddSqlServer()` I am not sure, where have you seen this.

There's no such official document I founded.

If you look at the [`SignalRDependencyInjectionExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.signalrdependencyinjectionextensions?view=aspnetcore-8.0) interface you would seen, there's no method which we could use  in order to pass `.AddMySql(options =>` or even the sql server connection string.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Therefore, according to your shared code snippet, or query, we cannot pass the connection string through `AddSignalR()`.

In addition, you could try within your HubClass. And it would be nicer if you could share more details about your hub class.

**Note:**  Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-signalr-hubs), this might be resourceful for you.